# iTunes Connect shows an update, but I didn't do any update for my app at all

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I find an update on my app from iTunes connect, but I am 100% sure I didn't do any update at all:[image]

Anyone could tell me why?

My app was first launched on Dec 7. Is it somehow related?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bug on their side. As you can see, "Change from last week" is 0%, should have been 100%. Based on a previous similar experience I've had, give it a day or two and it should fix itself.

Answer (score -1):

The graphic you posted isn't showing any updates it's just showing that you had one sale on Dec 16th.